# Syntax error in fresh copy of pyssh 0.3? (PYTHON)

Tags: python

I am trying to test out pyssh, however I am getting a syntax error whenever I try to import it.

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:29:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Corey\Desktop\Python\TheOne.py", line 1, in <module>
import SSHController
File "C:\Users\Corey\Desktop\Python\SSHController.py", line 19, in <module>
import pyssh
File "C:\Users\Corey\Desktop\Python\pyssh\__init__.py", line 82
print """User input required for ssh connection.
(Type Ctrl-C to abort connection.)"""

                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know pyssh does not support python 3.X, this is obvious from the error message you are getting.  In python 3.X the print statement is a function.